# JavaScript save sum to field

Tags: javascript

New to JavaScript.

I have a form with three fields, quantity, amount (hidden), sum.
The user enters the quantity they would like to buy and its multiplied with amount and shows the total in sum. If the user change the amount the sum changes. What I cant solve is how to save the sum in the field, when the user use checkout the sum fields ends up empty.

The script:

```js
function getElementByName(name) {
  const elements = document.getElementsByName(name)
  if (elements.length !== 1) {
    throw new Error('multiple elements found with name ' + name)
  }
  return elements[0]
}

/**
 * Calculate sum
 */
function calculateSum() {
  const num1 = getElementByName('quantity').value;
  const num2 = getElementByName('amount').value;
  getElementByName("sum").value = num1 * num2;
}

/**
 * Listen to events
 */
function listenToEvents() {
  const elem = getElementByName('quantity')
  elem.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    calculateSum()
  })
}
listenToEvents()
```

Comment: Please explain your problem statement properly. Its not clear from your question right now.

Comment: I use a form platform to create custom dynamic web forms. In this platform I can add javascript to my form, which Im now trying to do. The user enter the value of quantity the would like to buy and the script calculates the sum and show the user how much it will cost, then the user hits submit and an email is sent from the form with the quantity and sum, but the sum is empty. The value shows in the form and the user can change the quantity and sum changes, but it doesnt save the value. If I enter a value directly in the sum field it will be saved.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the event handler function inside a function. I will also suggest you to use `input` event instead of `keyup`. You can also attach the event on both *quantity* and *amount*.

**Demo:**

```js
function getElementByName(name) {
  const elements = document.getElementsByName(name)
  if (elements.length !== 1) {
    throw new Error('multiple elements found with name ' + name)
  }
  return elements[0]
}

/**
 * Calculate sum
 */
function calculateSum() {
  const num1 = getElementByName('quantity').value;
  const num2 = getElementByName('amount').value;
  getElementByName("sum").value = num1 * num2;
}

/**
 * Listen to events
 */
const elems = [getElementByName('quantity'),getElementByName('amount')]
elems.forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('input', () => {
    calculateSum()
  });
});
```

```html
Quantity: <input type="number" name="quantity"/><br><br>
Amount: <input type="number" name="amount"/><br><br>
Sum: <input name="sum"/>
```

Comment: If I use 'input' instead of 'keyup' in my form the value in sum field only flashes by and doesnt show for the user and when submitting the form the value from sum field is not saved. If I enter a value directly in the sum field its saved when submitting.